# How do I store in a .txt file the highest number(in words) from input numbers?

Tags: java, file, io, numbers

I am supposed to get the highest number from all input numbers and convert the highest number into words. Numbers in our language actually. I am kind of having trouble in storing it into a .txt file. My program stores the number but not the word, how can I make my program store the word and not the number?

```
public static int getHighest1(int ... dNums) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("Output1.txt");


   for (int iCtr=0; iCtr<dNums.length; iCtr++) {
        System.out.println("Values:" +dNums[iCtr]);
    }

    int dMax = 0;        
    for (int iCtr=0; iCtr<dNums.length; iCtr++) { 
        if (dMax<dNums[iCtr]) {
            dMax = dNums[iCtr];
        }
    }

    outFile.println("Ang pinakamataas na numero ay:" +dMax);

    int dTenThousands, dThousands, dHundreds, dTens, dOnes, dRemainder=0;

    dTenThousands = dMax/10000;
    dMax = dMax%10000;
    dThousands = dMax/1000;
    dMax = dMax%1000;
    dHundreds = dMax/100;
    dMax = dMax%100;
    dTens = (dMax%100)/10;

    if (dMax>10 && dMax <20) {
        dTens = 0;
        dOnes = 0;
        dRemainder=dMax%10;
    }

    else {
        dTens = dMax/10;
        dOnes = dMax;
    }

    switch(dTenThousands) {
        case 1: System.out.print("Sampung libo"); break; 
        case 2: System.out.print("Dalawgpung libo"); break;
        case 3: System.out.print("Tatlunpung libo"); break;
        case 4: System.out.print("Apatnapung libo"); break;
        case 5: System.out.print("Limangpung libo"); break;
        case 6: System.out.print("Animnapung libo"); break;
        case 7: System.out.print("Pitongpung libo"); break;
        case 8: System.out.print("Walongpung libo"); break;
        case 9: System.out.print("Siyamnapung libo"); break;
    }

    switch(dThousands) {
        case 1: System.out.print("Isang libo"); break; 
        case 2: System.out.print("Dalawang libo"); break;
        case 3: System.out.print("Tatlong libo"); break;
        case 4: System.out.print("Apat na libo"); break;
        case 5: System.out.print("Limang libo"); break;
        case 6: System.out.print("Anim na libo"); break;
        case 7: System.out.print("Pitong libo"); break;
        case 8: System.out.print("Walong libo"); break;
        case 9: System.out.print("Siyam na libo"); break;
    }

    switch(dHundreds) {
        case 1: System.out.print("Isandaan"); break; 
        case 2: System.out.print("Dalawandaan"); break;
        case 3: System.out.print("Tatlundaan"); break;
        case 4: System.out.print("Apatnadaan"); break;
        case 5: System.out.print("Limangdaan"); break;
        case 6: System.out.print("Animnaraan"); break;
        case 7: System.out.print("Pitongraan"); break;
        case 8: System.out.print("Walongraan"); break;
        case 9: System.out.print("Siyam naraan"); break; 
    }

    switch(dRemainder) {
        case 1: System.out.print("Labingisa"); break; 
        case 2: System.out.print("Labindalawa"); break;
        case 3: System.out.print("Labintatlo"); break;
        case 4: System.out.print("Labing apat"); break;
        case 5: System.out.print("Labinlima"); break;
        case 6: System.out.print("Labing anim"); break;
        case 7: System.out.print("Labing pito"); break;
        case 8: System.out.print("Labing walo"); break;
        case 9: System.out.print("Labing siyam"); break; 
    }

    switch(dTens) {
        case 1: System.out.print("Sampu"); break; 
        case 2: System.out.print("Dalawampu"); break;
        case 3: System.out.print("Tatlumpu"); break;
        case 4: System.out.print("Apatnapu"); break;
        case 5: System.out.print("Limampu"); break;
        case 6: System.out.print("Animnapu"); break;
        case 7: System.out.print("Pitumpu"); break;
        case 8: System.out.print("Walumpu"); break;
        case 9: System.out.print("Siyamnapu"); break; 
    }

    switch(dOnes) {
        case 1: System.out.print("Isa"); break; 
        case 2: System.out.print("Dalawa"); break;
        case 3: System.out.print("Tatlo"); break;
        case 4: System.out.print("Apat"); break;
        case 5: System.out.print("Lima"); break;
        case 6: System.out.print("Anim"); break;
        case 7: System.out.print("Pito"); break;
        case 8: System.out.print("Walo"); break;
        case 9: System.out.print("Siyam"); break; 
    }

    System.out.println("\nAng pinamataas na numero ay:" +dMax);

}
```

My code's not yet finished but I've tried storing my maximumnumber into the output.txt file. But the text file contains the number, not the word, help please? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Change all your:

```
case n: System.out.print("xxx"); break;
```

to

```
case n: outFile.print("xxx"); break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the System.out.print in the switch...cases to outFile.print.

Answer (score 0):

The other way is to organize your output as string value, and after that you may do everything what you want with your result. And write to file with File.write() .